# Creating multiple CSS2DRenderer is not possible

Tags: three.js

I have a WebGLRenderer with a CSS2DRenderer on my page. Similar to this example:

https://threejs.org/examples/#css2d_label

Now I want to add the rendered scene including all labels into a pdf. Both scaled up to fit a whole A4 page. For that I need to scale the size without changing the current renderers. So I thought I could just create two new renderers, scale their sizes and add them to my pdf document.

That works flawlessly for the WebGlRenderer but the problem is that it seems that you can not have more than one CSS2dRenderer. The secondly added doesn't add CSS2DObjects to it's htmlelement.

I know this is a very rare use case but one of you might have an idea how to get that working.

Comment: I've modified the official example to demonstrate that it's no problem to use more than a single instance of `CSS2DRenderer`. The mentioned problem does not occur. As you can see, the second label renderer renders an additional dummy label in the center of the scene: https://jsfiddle.net/x8rhqcse/

Comment: thanks for your example. It was an issue in my code. I had an inherrited object from CS2DObject which didn't get copied correctly. That's why nothing was shown. Now everything works like a charm. Thank you again :)